# Astro dynamic routing (SSR mode) and 404 page

Tags: typescript, http-status-code-404, astrojs

I am using [Astro](https://astro.build) and [Apollo client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) to fetch data using GraphQL.

In Astro I am using SSR only.

I have set up the following [Astro dynamic routing](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#server-ssr-mode) (SSR mode):

```
// [...slug].astro

---
import Page from '../components/page/Page.astro';
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
---

<Layout title="Test">
  <Page />
</Layout>
```

And `Page.astro`:

```
// Page.astro
---
import PageOne from '../PageOne.astro';
import PageTwo from '../PageTwo.astro';

const uri = `/${Astro.params.uri}`;

const { data, loading } = await client.query<
  GetPageQuery,
  GetPageQueryVariables
>({
  query: GET_PAGE,
  variables: {
    url: uri,
  },
});

const Map = {
  "PageOne": PageOne,
  "PageTwo": PageTwo,
};


const Component = Map[data.page?.type];
---

{loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
{!loading && <Component uri={uri} />}
```

This is all working fine. So when I request a request an existing route/path `uri` (which exist in the backend), I can query the `type` (data.page?.type) and then I map to the proper Astro component, e.g `PageOne` or `PageOne` (.astro). However when I navigate to a non-existing url I get an error:

> Unable to render Component because it is undefined! Did you forget to
> import the component or is it possible there is a typo?

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just add a check if the component is valid and then redirect (or do something else) e.g.

```js
const Component = Map[data.page?.type];

if (!Component) {
  return Astro.redirect("/404");
}
```

Comment: ok good that's working now for the pages which has a route defined from the backend but without a component yet. So that part is solved with above. But with a non-existing page e.g. `http://localhost:4321/xxx` I get this error: `ApolloError
items must be defined`. How to solve this?

Comment: In my page component something like `
if (!data) {
  return new Response(null, {
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'Not found',
  });
}` or `if (!data) {
  return Astro.redirect('/404');
}` doesn't work?

Comment: What does this `items` code look like? You just need to add some error handling for it, just like with `Component`.

Comment: That's the strange thing. I am not requesting `items` somewhere?

Comment: Do you have a repo to look at? It seems you're using Apollo on a dynamic route e.g. `[page].astro`? Start with your use of Apollo.

Comment: yes that's correct see my description it's happening inside `[...slug].astro`.

Comment: I found it, seems to work when adding `errorPolicy: 'all',` to the query.

Comment: Last question. See my above setup. I am having a <Page /> astro component where I do the query etc. That doesn't work because you can do `return Astro.redirect("/404");` only inside an Astro page component. So when I move all code to `[...slug].astro` it's working.  How do extract the `Page` code to it's own component? I want this because I want the GraphQL query in its own file inside `src/component/page/Page.gql.ts` file.

Comment: Usually you would just use a page e.g. `[...slug].astro` like you said. Is there a reason for the separate Page component to try and handle page stuff from there? 

Otherwise you can move the query code to `Page.gql.ts`, call that function from the page you want, and redirect if the query isn't valid i.e. not a valid page.